Is there any way I can marry this brother without my wali (father)
Assalamu alaikum, I am a Kuwaiti (Mālikī)who has been hoping to marry this man (he is Iraqi), however when I brought the matter up to my father he rejected the idea right away and got very angry at the suggestion of me marrying an iraqi, his only reason was the fact that he is non-kuwaiti and he does not want me marrying someone who is not Kuwaiti. I have also brought this up to my brothers and uncle however they all rejected the idea and refused to listen due to the same cultural reason. I have read that that is an invalid reason to reject a marriage. No matter how many times I ask or plead them to just meet him they keep rejecting the idea. Me and this brother really want to get married, although I have no committed any haram with him I fear I may in the future and it’s better for both of us to marry ASAP we are both very frustrated right now. And I see no other reason why we cannot get married  he is a pious man, very religious and is able to support us, there is no reason why we cannot marry other than cultural differences. Please help us, is there any way possible I can marry him with someone else as my wali?
